# Android Error: "Not a Statement" in a specific block of code

Tags: android

i am getting this error (not a statement) for this block of code:
Please Suggest some solution if anyone is having

```
else{
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Swipe down to update the list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show;
 swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable()
 {
    @Override
    public void run(){
      swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
      fetchMovies();
    }
 }
 );
}
```

Comment: which error? stacktrace please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Toast.show` is a method, not a property. It should be called as `show()` with the brackets at the end:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Swipe down to update the list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

`*.show` is not a statement -> change it to `*.show()`